# Reprovision a Windows 10 package

Tags: windows-10, package-management, uwp, windows-packagemanagement

I've mistakenly unprovisioned the Paint 3d (MS Paint) appx package using

```
Get-appxprovisionedpackage -online | where-object {$_.packagename -like "*paint*"} | remove-appxprovisionedpackage -online
```

and now I'm having difficulties to provision it back again.

It is still installed and working, though. How do I reprovision it again? Preferably using the already locally installed copy, without downloading an entire ISO again.

Comment: If it’s installed and working, what exactly is your question?

Comment: To make it provisioned again so it will be installed for every new user

Comment: You will need a Windows 10 ISO for the same version you have installed in order to reprovision the application in question.  The command you ran removed it from WinSxS which means, while the application was not uninstalled for the user that ran the command, it won't be installed for any future users. You can go to the Store on any other user and simply reinstall it, but in order to put it back on your system like it was before, will require the ISO

Comment: Well, if there really isn't any other way I guess I'll do that, feel free to repost this comment as an answer so I can flag it as an answer for you